# Trigger enter key press automatically into a text field when page is loaded using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger enter key pressed in a text field when a page will be loaded.Suppose when user will load the page a text-field will trigger automatically enter key press event means the text field function should remain same as enter key pressed on keyboard.I have a text filed given below.

```
<input type="text"  id="txt-field" >
```

Manually when user is pressing enter key form key-board one function is executing which is given below.

```
function scan(){
alert('hello');
}
```

But I need this function will execute when page will be load and this text field trigger with enter key event.

Comment: call your function on page load

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger a keypress-event for a specific key when you construct the jQuery Event Object manually. You can assign an event and some properties which will be set on this object.

```
var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 13 } );
$("#txt-field").trigger(e);
```

In the following line, `e` contains the above created event-object with the assigned properties:

```
$('#txt-field').on('keydown', function (e) {
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8t189gv5/)

Side-Note: There might be some cross-browser issues when the keycodes are different in the browser.

If you only want to trigger the function onload:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    scan();
});
```

**Reference**

[jQuery - Event](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: its not working in jquery 1.10.2. Is there any equivalent syntax in 1.10.2 for same functionality?

Comment: @MannVerma why would you want to use such an old version? The current version is 3.3. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: I have a dynamically created text field in javascript. I just want to trigger it's enter key event when it losts focus(onblur).